# SMTPAuthenticationError code 535 with python

Tags: python, smtp, gmail, smtplib

I tried with "allow less secure app" and "unlockCaptcha", but still not work.
How to know if the problem is with my account or with the code?
Thanks for attention, here teh code:

```
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
import smtplib

# Import the email modules we'll need
from email.message import EmailMessage

# create message object instance
msg = MIMEMultipart()
 
message = "Prova"

# setup the parameters of the message
password="pass"
msg['From'] = "senders@example.com"
msg['To'] = "receiver@example.com"
msg['Subject'] = "Prova"

# add in the message body
msg.attach(MIMEText(message, 'plain'))
 
#create server
server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
server.ehlo()
server.starttls()
server.ehlo()
# Login Credentials for sending the mail
server.login(msg['From'], password)

# send the message via the server.
server.sendmail(msg['From'], msg['To'], msg.as_string())
 
server.quit()
 
print(f"successfully sent email to {msg['To']}")
```

Comment: Tangentially, you don't need a `multipart` if you only have one part. Simply make the main message a `text/plain`.

Comment: The result you get from `msg["from"]` is probably  normalized so it's not suitable as the user name string directly.